# orca_vpot problem

Tags: orca, charge-density, electrostatic

I'm trying to calculate the electrostatic potential of a molecule. When I try to use the `orca_vpot` tool, I am facing some difficulties detailed below.

The first problem is that when I run the input with the `KeepDens` keyword to generate the `.scfp` file, it only generates a `.densities` file. When I try to use this file instead of the `.scfp` file in the `orca_vpot` tool, it shows the following error:

```
file orca_tools/qcmat1.cpp, line 103: Stored DataType 7403560 does not 
match the expected 8 in OrcaObject_ReadHeader!
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to MMSE ! You can format relevant parts of your question using code blocks to make your question more readable. This can be done putting the required text in between triple backward quotes  ```     some text      ```

Comment: It may be a good idea to ask this question on the ORCA forum (https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/index.php), or search for related questions on that forum. Questions on the ORCA forum will in general be answered rather quickly by ORCA developers.

Comment: @VandanRevanur thenks for the help with the format of the text

Comment: @wzkchem5 Thank you for the tip. Already did this. Thanks again